# Copy of array not changing when passed through method

Tags: java, arrays, copying

I am trying to use 4 different methods I created on the same array, but when I pass a copy of the original array through the second method it prints out the same array that was printed after the original array was passed through the first method.

Both methods work fine if the original array is passed through them.

```
public class ArrayPractice
{

    static double[] values = new double[11]; 
    Random randomInt = new Random();         //apparently main can't use nonstatic     field values

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //when methods are created run them each once for the array we created and     then print out the result.
        ArrayPractice AP = new ArrayPractice();

        AP.fillArray(values);
        double[] valuesCopyOne = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length); //use this     to run the original array through the methods rather than the modified array
        AP.printArray(values);
        System.out.println();

        AP.firstLastSwap(values);
        AP.printArray(values);
        System.out.println();

        AP.shiftElementsLeft(valuesCopyOne); //deal with using the copy after this     method is fixed
        AP.printArray(valuesCopyOne);
        System.out.println();

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger to make sure your variables contain what you expect them to at each line of code?

Comment: Post complete code if that may help

Comment: Do you change the values of the array once it passes through the first method. That would imply that you are then passing into the second method the new values as changed by method 1.

Comment: well I put he copyOf call where it is because I wanted it to save the randomly generated array values in the copy. I change the values of the original array in firstLastSwap, but I wanted to use the copy of the initial order of the values for shiftElementsLeft.